# Set addition between A and B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$U = \mathbb{R}^2, A = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}, B = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y = x, 0 \leq x \leq 1 \}$$

How can be addition be:

$$A+B= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid (x−z)^2+(y−z)^2 \leq 1,0 \leq z \leq 1 \}$$

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(u,v) \in A+B$, then there exists $(x,y) \in A$ and $(t,t) \in B$ with $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ and $0 \leq t \leq 1$ such that
$$(u,v)=(x,y)+(t,t)=(x+t,y+t).$$
Then $x=u-t$ and $y=v-t$. Furthermore
$$x^2+y^2 \leq 1\implies (u-t)^2+(v-t)^2 \leq 1, \qquad \text{ with } 0 \leq t \leq 1. $$